# How bad are typos in PhD interview emails?

Tags: phd, interview

The typo I'm talking about is literally one wrong letter.

Comment: You will get more informed answers if you give more detail and context to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not career ending, but they should be avoided. People generally are pretty tolerant of simple mistakes, especially in email. But you should proof read any important communication.

If the typo actually substituted one valid word for another, however, it could be a bit worse, depending on the words "where" v "whore" could require a re-send, and and explanation.

But if it is benign and not repeated then it isn't likely anything to be concerned about.

---

Exceptions might occur if your email was to an extremely exacting and formal person or in a field in which exactness is a supreme virtue.